# ASM under ARM - Instruction mov

Tags: assembly, arm, mov

I'm a biginner with the ASM language and i would like to know how i can set the value -1894025488 to the register `r0` ?

If the value is "10", then it's right

```
mov r0, #10
```

HEX -> 0A00A0E3

But, if the value is bigger than "1024" as "-1894025488", then i can't convert in hexa

```
mov r0, #-1894025488
```

HEX -> I can't convert in Hexa

Can you help me ?

Comment: The cutoff isn't `1024`. To load arbitrary numbers you can use `ldr, =number` form (see the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/dom1359731147386.html)). Note that this will use a literal pool for the values that can not be directly encoded.

Comment: I tryed with ldr.

ldr r0, =10 is right

ldr r0, =-1894025488 wrong i don't find the haxa convert

Comment: There isn't a single machine code for that, since it depends on where in the literal pool the constant has been placed. Read the documentation I linked to see that it will get translated into `LDR      rn, [pc, #offset to literal pool]`

Comment: Can you help me with a sample ?

If i understand, i must do : ldr r0, &memory
but which instruction i can set &memory=-1894025488

Comment: _"but which instruction i can set &memory=-1894025488"_ That's not done by any instruction. The assembler places the value -1894025488 in a [literal pool](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Bgbccbdi.html), which then can be loaded with a PC-relative `LDR` (for which `LDR reg,=immediate` is syntactic sugar), as Jester has already explained.

Comment: Thx, I understand now and it's work. I did :

set *&addr = -1894025488
ldr     r0, [pc, #-24]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the arm instructions in the arm documentation, it should become obvious from that.

First off if you have a computer you can convert that number to hex, but shouldnt necessarily need to.

there are three major arm instruction sets, arm, thumb and the thumb2 extensions to arm (ones that have a mov).  each has different rules for immediate values.  If you think about it you are wanting to load 0x8F1B76f0 into a register, that is clearly a 32 bit number which is not mostly ones or mostly zeros.  the arm instructions are 32 bits and the thumb are 16 or 16+16 (32).  it is not possible to put 32 bits of immediate plus some opcode bits in to say this is a mov and what register and have that all fit in 32 bits, cant squeeze 32+N bits into 32, so just like MIPS you have to do something else.   the arm solution is to take advantage of the barrel shifters so you have around 8 significant bits and can shift them into various locations.  So for example with an arm instruction you can do

```
mov r0,#0x86000000
```

because the non-zero bits are within a group of 8  (10000110....) that can be shifted around.  with thumb though I dont think it works that way but not sure.

there is a shortcut

```
ldr r0,=0x8F1B76f0
```

which is clearly meant to let the assembler fill in addresses from label names but you can cheat and put a value in there.

but all that does is have the assembler generate a pc relative load

```
ldr r0,temp
...
temp : .word 0x8F1B76f0
```

so that is the proper way to always be able to load any constant, and all three instruction sets support a pc relative word sized load.